# How to check the connection status in java using jdbc connection?

Tags: java, ms-access

How to handle sql exceptions in Msaccess jdbc connection? I'm retrieving data from msaccess using jdbc connection in java. If connection fail i need to show-up the custom message instead of throwing exception.

```
public static Connection getConnection()  {
    Connection connection = null;
    try
    {
        String url = "jdbc:odbc:db1";
        String username = "";
        String password = "";
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        connection= DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Report");
    }
    return connection;
  }
```

But its not handling the custom message.its throwing error :
**java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object**

Comment: Have you tried catching exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location where you are calling getConnection, provide custom message there by handling exception:

```
Connection con = null;
try {
     con = DatabaseUtil.getConnection();
    ...
    ...
}catch(Exception e) {
   //show message, dialog box, whatever
} finally {
   if(con != null) {
         try{
            con.close();
         }catch(SQLException sqe){
              //yet another message, unable to close connection cleanly.
         }
   }
}
```

P.S. Its a bad idea to declare "Exception", you should always try to throw most relevant exception from your method. SQLException makes more sense in DatabaseUtil.getConnection

P.P.S. Class.forName(driver); is only required once per JVM invocation (for JDBC driver registration). Hence, the appropriate place to register your JDBC drivers is in a static initializer (which is called once when your class is loaded for the first time).

Answer (score 1):

You can not avoid exceptions. Instead of throwing them, you can handle them by using

```
 try{
     // do Something
  } catch(SqlException e){
     // catch exception 
  } finally {
  // do something to get recover 
  }
```

[For more info follow this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot avoid the SQLException being thrown.  The JDBC APIs don't provide a method to test connection liveness.

To test if a JDBC connection is (still) valid, you perform a simple query.  The "dummy query" idiom for doing this varies with the database, but any query on any of your tables will suffice.  If the connection is not alive you will get an exception ... which you need to handle.

**However** it is possible for the database connection to die *between you testing the connection and then performing your real query* (or whatever).  So (IMO) you are better off just writing your code so that it can deal with the SQLException in a real query ... and not bother probing.  This also gives better performance, because repeatedly testing to see if a JDBC connection is alive is going to add useless load to your application ... and the database.